# ScrollView hide button in relative layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have 3 components to show in my app:
Inside a layout with a background I want to set: TextView + ScrollView + Button at the bottom

This is the code I have done so far:

```
<RelativeLayout style="@style/fill_parent" android:background="@layout/shapetablehome" android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageUser" android:layout_below="@+id/userblock">
    <LinearLayout style="@style/fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/boxcomment">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textTime" android:textSize= "18dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/black"            
            style="@style/wrap_content" android:text="Comento sobre Alicante" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">
        </TextView>
        <ScrollView style="@style/fill_parent">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textTime" android:textSize= "18dip" android:textColor="@color/black"
                style="@style/wrap_content" android:text="Comentario sobre Alicante Comentario sobre Alicante
                Comentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre Alicante
                Comentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre Alicante
                Comentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre Alicante
                Comentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre Alicante
                Comentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre AlicanteComentario sobre Alicante" 
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textTime" android:paddingTop="10dp">
            </TextView>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
<Button android:id="@+id/btRegister" style="@style/wrap_content" android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp" 
    android:background="@layout/selectoryellowbutton" android:textSize="20px" android:layout_height="42dip" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:text="Escribir a Inma Bermejo">
</Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is when the comment is too long the text on the ScrollView position behind the button. If I set the button to be below the linerLayout with the textView+ ScrollView,
like:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btRegister" style="@style/wrap_content" android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp" android:layout_below="@+id/boxcomment"
    android:background="@layout/selectoryellowbutton" android:textSize="20px" android:layout_height="42dip" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:text="Escribir a Inma Bermejo">
</Button>
```

The button doesnt appear. I could have used a LinerLayout with the 3 components, but I want the button to position always at the bottom of the layout.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Binding button to the bottom of the screen can be done in LinearLayout using android:layout_gravity="bottom"

Comment: that sounds very interesting :)

Comment: @Egor: Still the button is hiden by the scrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using the parameter android:layout_above="@+id/btRegister" for the LinearLayout. Is analog to use the solution I mention before, of using the parameter android:layout_below="@+id/boxcomment" for the button...
But for some reason I dont understand the button is hidden whereas using the first it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use value `fill_parent` as a height of the `boxcomment` view if you want something to be below this view. Use `layout_height="0dip"` and `layout_weight="1"` for this `LinearLayout`.

Comment: using <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" layout_height="0dip" layout_weight="1">
Produces an error which says that I must supply an attribute for layout_height

Comment: That's because you forgot to add `android` namespace to this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

add `android:layout_below="@+id/boxcomment"` to your Button and give a try again.